# Primitive of $u'' /u$

Tags: integration

There is a primitive for
$$f'(x)/f(x)$$
which is
$\ln(f(x))$
but is there any known primitive for
$f''(x)/f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

There's isn't, in general, an elementary primitive for $f''(x)/f(x)$. Take, for example, $f=\log$. The integral $\int\frac{-1}{x^2\log(x)}\,dx$ can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.